# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring, vue.js, cors

I'm getting CORS error working with VueJS and Spring. VueJS calls REST WS with POST. I've tried below to allow CORS by creating CorsConfiguration and adding origin, header and method but it didn't work. Appreciate some help.

Browser

```
OPTIONS https://test/example/ 403

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test/example/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Spring

```
@Configuration
public class CustomCORSConfiguration {

    private CorsConfiguration buildConfig() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        return corsConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", buildConfig());
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Vue

```
//POST
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    strictSSL: false,
    changeOrigin:true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,//add when working with https sites
    requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
    agent: false//add when working with https sites
}
const reqBody = {
        "shopCode": "ASCDASDCASD",
        "amount": this.total_price,
        "authToken": "EDSAACDSAD"
}

this.axios.post(api, reqBody, config).then(response => {
    if (response) {
        const data = response.data
        console.log(data)
        this.qrUrl = data.data
         console.log(this.qrUrl)
        //if (this.qrUrl) {
           // this.loading=false
            location.href = this.qrUrl
        //}
    }
}).catch(e => {
    this.errors=e
    alert(e)
    console.log(this.errors)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the line

```
corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
```

thus you code will look like

```
CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
```